# how to move projectile in an arc to mouse x,y with AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I've read a number of similar questions to this on here, but unfortunately none of them seem to give the exact answer I'm after, or they might but the maths is beyond me!

I'm creating a game where you have a cannon at the left edge of the screen. I want to be able to fire a cannonball from the cannon in an arc so that it intersects where the mouse pointer is on the screen.

I've seen a few examples that move a projectile in an arc from point a to point b, but what I need is for the cannonball to first move along the axis of the cannon itself, it's no good if the ball leaves the end of the cannon at a different angle to which the cannon is pointing.

The only force acting on the ball will be gravity and it's starting velocity.

Also to complicate matters, I need the cannons angle to change according to how far away the mouse pointer is from the end of the cannon, so if the pointer is far away than the cannon will point upwards say at an angle of 45 degrees, but if the pointer is very close to the end of the cannon then the cannon will point directly at the pointer, this I've more or less already got working by just getting the distance between them and then dividing it by a number and subtracting it from the rotation value of the cannon, but it's a bit of a rough way of doing it.

**EDIT**
Using the code below I've managed to the line in the screen shot below. But as you can see it's not the trajectory I need, I need something more like the red line I've put in.

[image: line]

And here's how I've implemented the code (probably wrongly)

```
public class GameTurretLine2
    {
        var rt:Object = null;
        var lineMc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

        var myTurret:GameMainGun = null;

        var pta:Point = new Point(0,0);
        var ptb:Point = new Point(0,0);
        var ptc:Point = new Point(0,0);
        var ptd:Point = new Point(0,0);

        public function GameTurretLine2(rt2,turret)
        {
            rt = rt2;
            myTurret = turret;

            lineMc.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x55aa00); 

            mainLoop();

            rt.rt.GameLayers.turretLineMc.addChild(lineMc);

        }
        function mainLoop()
        {

            lineMc.graphics.clear();

            //get points
            var turretEnd:Object = myTurret.rt.Useful.localToGlobalXY(myTurret.mC.turret.firePoint);
            var turretStart:Object = myTurret.rt.Useful.localToGlobalXY(myTurret.mC.turret);
            var mousePos:Point = new Point(myTurret.rt.rt.mouseX,myTurret.rt.rt.mouseY);
            var inbetween:Point = new Point(0,0);

            //start
            pta.x = turretStart.newX;
            pta.y = turretStart.newY;

            //mouse end
            ptd.x = mousePos.x;
            ptd.y = mousePos.y;

            // The cannon's angle:
            // make the cannon's angle some inverse factor 
            // of the distance between the mouse and cannon tip 

            var dist:Number = myTurret.rt.Useful.getDistance(turretEnd.newX, turretEnd.newY, mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
            var cAng:Number = dist * (180/Math.PI);

            var ptbc:Point = new Point((ptd.x - pta.x) *.5,0);
            ptbc.y = Math.tan(cAng) * ptbc.x; 

            //ptb = new Point(ptbc.x - ptbc.x * .15, ptbc.y);
            ptb = new Point(turretEnd.newX, turretEnd.newY);
            ptc = new Point(ptbc.x + ptbc.x * .5, ptbc.y);

            // create the Bezier:
            var bz:BezierSegment = new BezierSegment(pta,ptb,ptc,ptd);
            trace(bz); 

            // define the distance between points that you want to draw 
            // has to be between 0 and 1. 
            var stepVal:Number = .1; 
            var curPt:Point = pta; 

            //draw circles

            lineMc.graphics.drawCircle(pta.x, pta.y, 4); 
            lineMc.graphics.drawCircle(ptb.x, ptb.y, 4); 
            lineMc.graphics.drawCircle(ptc.x, ptc.y, 4); 
            lineMc.graphics.drawCircle(ptd.x, ptd.y, 4); 

            lineMc.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x0000ff); 

            //step along the curve to draw it 
            for(var t:Number = 0;t < 1;t+=stepVal){
                lineMc.graphics.moveTo(curPt.x, curPt.y);
                curPt = bz.getValue(t); 
                trace("curPt = " + curPt.x  + "," + curPt.y);
                lineMc.graphics.lineTo(curPt.x, curPt.y);
            } 

            trace("pta = " + pta.x  + "," + pta.y);
            trace("ptb = " + ptb.x  + "," + ptb.y);
            trace("ptc = " + ptc.x  + "," + ptc.y);
            trace("ptd = " + ptd.x  + "," + ptd.y);


        }
    }
```

Also for some strange reason, the line created by the code flips, from how it is in the screen shot to an indented code (y flipped) just by moving the mouse a tiny amount, so as you move the mouse the line jumps everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to create a Bezier curve.

This sounds like a workable solution because you essentially want the curve to always fit under some triangle.  If this triangle defines the control points for a Bezier curve, you can make that match pretty closely the arc of a cannonball under gravity (it's not a perfect representation of gravity).  One side-effect of this method is that the (inversed) height can define the force of the cannonball.

You can use the [fl.motion.BezierSegment](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/motion/BezierSegment.html) to create a curve and step along it.  Paste this code into an FLA:

```
import fl.motion.BezierSegment;

var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();   
addChild(mySprite);
mySprite.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x55aa00);

// End point of the cannon:
var pta:Point = new Point(0, 100);
mySprite.graphics.drawCircle(pta.x, pta.y, 4);
trace("pta = " + pta.x  + "," + pta.y);

// mouse point
// var ptd:Point = new Point(mouseX, mouseY);
// for testing: 
var ptd:Point = new Point(200,100);
mySprite.graphics.drawCircle(ptd.x, ptd.y, 4);
trace("ptd = " + ptd.x  + "," + ptd.y);

// The cannon's angle:
// make the cannon's angle some inverse factor 
// of the distance between the mouse and cannon tip
// var dx:Number = ptd.x-pta.x;
// var dy:Number = ptd.y-pta.y;
// var dist:Number = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
var cAng:Number = 30 *  /(180/Math.PI);

// point the cannon in the correct direction here, however you are intending to do that.

// triangulate the cannon pt and mouse pt assuming the cannon's angle for both:
// *** NOTE: for simplicity, this assumes a straight line on the x-plane. ***
var ptbc:Point = new Point((ptd.x - pta.x) *.5,0);
ptbc.y = Math.tan(cAng) * ptbc.x; 
trace("ptbc = " + ptbc.x  + "," + ptbc.y);

// to adjust the curve:
var ptb:Point = new Point(ptbc.x - ptbc.x * .15, ptbc.y);
var ptc:Point = new Point(ptbc.x + ptbc.x * .5, ptbc.y);
mySprite.graphics.drawCircle(ptb.x, ptb.y, 4);
mySprite.graphics.drawCircle(ptc.x, ptc.y, 4);

// create the Bezier:
var bz:BezierSegment = new BezierSegment(pta,ptb,ptc,ptd);
trace(bz);

// define the distance between points that you want to draw
// has to be between 0 and 1.
var stepVal:Number = .1;
var curPt:Point = pta;

mySprite.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x0000ff);

//step along the curve to draw it
for(var t:Number = 0;t < 1;t+=stepVal){
    mySprite.graphics.moveTo(curPt.x, curPt.y);
    curPt = bz.getValue(t);
    trace("curPt = " + curPt.x  + "," + curPt.y);
    mySprite.graphics.lineTo(curPt.x, curPt.y);
}

mySprite.x = stage.stageWidth/2-mySprite.width/2;
mySprite.y = stage.stageHeight/2-mySprite.height/2;
```

As is, this code is not attached directly to the mouse, so you will have to use your own `MouseEvent` and AdjustCannonEvent to run this code.  (Also, make sure to see the note in the code.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't quite understand this bit 
var ptbc:Point = new Point((ptd.x - pta.x) *.5,0); ptbc.y = Math.tan(cAng) * ptbc.x
you say assumes a straight line but the mouse pointer can be anywhere on the screen so, wouldn't there be an angle between the end cannon point and the mouse pointer x,y?

Comment: Yes.  But my answer was laying out the basic idea of curve placement and curve height adjustment.  It is a lot more complicated to define a non-x-linear angle, though I think that there are some general solutions out there.

Comment: Also note that the projectile should start at the cannon tip, not the cannon's rotation point.  You can simply rotate the cannon, pick some point on the end, and use localToGlobal() to convert it to a useable position against the mouse.

Comment: I've already got the end point, but to me it looks like the curve should start at the origin, and then head towards the end of the cannon, and then there's a mid point between the end of the cannon and the mouse point, but I wasn't able to get that looking right, thanks anyway.